# Size of an internal Sqlite db in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

In Android there is a built-in SQLite DB. How can we get the maximum size of built-in Sqlite DB?

Some says that it depends upon device internal memory. If so, how vault app is hiding large amount of datas(like pix,videos,applications,etc.).

Can anyone give me the clear idea regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

I had read that the `sqlite` database file have a maximum size of 140 TB. So on the phone it usually is limited by your mass memory size(2 gd and so on). the memory size will limit how much data you can retrieve from a query. Android Cursors have a limit of 1 MB for the results.

This [Link](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) may help with respect to other limitations on values in a sqlite database. I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats informative, then you are about to say that the minimum size of internal db is 2gb?

Comment: what am saying is that its limit is the size of your memory in your phone(may it be anything). ofcourse no phone will have memory of more than 140 TB at the present in our world at this moment.